# Merge in GitHub pull requests, possibly making changes to them first

Tags: github, pull-request

I recently started managing a project on GitHub where people have been submitting pull requests. Rather than merge them to master, I would like the ability to:

1. First vet them to make sure they actually work
2. Possibly making some stylistic changes before merging to master

How can I do this?

Do you have to make a separate branch, such as "dev", and instruct people to code against that before you merge to master?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/) page on this which details how to make changes to a pull request by checking out pull requests locally.

What I might try is first creating a remote for the pull request submitter (I'm using the examples from the above page):

```
git remote add kneath git://github.com/kneath/jobs.git
```

Fetch the changes:

```
git fetch kneath
```

Check out the branch in question (ex. master):

```
git checkout kneath/master
```

Vet them however you like, since the code that will be there will be the pull request code. Run tests, etc.

Merge them in if you're good to go:

```
git checkout master
git merge kneath/master
```

Further, here is a very good page on git [project management workflows](http://progit.org/book/ch5-2.html) which details the various workflows one can take on collaboration integration.

Comment: You actually don't even need that many commands.  Click the (i) on the left side of the merge bar and it will give you all the commands you need.

Comment: Oh okay, like I said I just took them from the github help page I linked to. I defer to your knowledge though since I'm sure you know more.

Answer (score 23):

A faster way of doing things with GitHub is to use this GitHub feature presented by [Zach Holman](https://twitter.com/holman) in his [GitHub Secrets II Talk](https://speakerdeck.com/holman/more-git-and-github-secrets?slide=114) ([video](http://zachholman.com/talk/more-git-and-github-secrets/)).

```
git fetch origin pull/id/head:name
```

Where `id` is the pull request id, `head` is the remote branch (on the fork), and `name` is the name you want to give the local branch. For example:

```
git fetch origin pull/12/head:pr
```

Fetches pull request #12 into a branch named *pr*.

You can add this as an alias in git if you use this a lot.

Comment: Nice trick. The `head` string is actually `head` though, not the branch name (f.i. `master`).

Comment: I have successfully cloned the PR locally, made changes, and now want to merge. How do I merge?