# Adding commits to another person's pull request on GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My project on GitHub has received a [pull request](https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor/pull/45). The pull request only partly fixes the issue that it's addressing. I've pulled in the changes to a local branch and added some commits of my own.

I'd now like to push those commits back to my remote repo and have them show up on the pull request, but without merging them into the target branch. I'd like to keep the pull request open for further review and discussion, and potentially further commits.

Is there a way I can add commits to the pull request without merging them into the target branch and therefore closing the pull request?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Haha, wow, I have no idea how I swapped links. I meant this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947322/preferred-github-workflow-for-updating-a-pull-request-after-code-review?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link Chris but that question is from the perspective of the pull request submitter, not the receiver. It seems that Henry Blyth's answer below is correct - it's currently not possible to do what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good way to merge in Github pull requests and possibly making changes to them first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474942/whats-a-good-way-to-merge-in-github-pull-requests-and-possibly-making-changes-t)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As long as the original author has clicked the checkbox in the bottom right:

[image: Allow Maintainers]

If that box is checked, then you can push back to the original branch without needing to add a remote by using:

```
git push git@github.com:user/repo local_branch_name:remote_branch_name
```

This is particularly useful if you're using a tool like [hub](http://hub.github.com) where you can check out a pull request without needing to add a remote.

**Edit:** You also need to have write access to the repository where the PR has been opened.

**Further Edit:** The [new command line tool](https://cli.github.com) from GitHub does a good job of checking out PRs so that you can just use `git push` as is to push updates to remotes (assuming you have permission).

Comment: Do you know if the command you wrote is somehow easier to do with hub?

My best workflow thus far has been to first `hub pr checkout ###`, then make changes, and then use your listed command.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a hub command to do this. I've not been using `hub` nearly as much lately though so it's possible that it could have been added.

Comment: Is this possible even if I am not the original author of the repository on which the PR has been sent? I receive an ERROR message: "Permission to user/repository.git denied to myself"

Comment: Two things have to be true: 1) The original author must have checked that box, and 2) you must have write access to the repository that the PR is made against.

Answer (score 40):

It is possible to do this now ([link](https://code.mendhak.com/update-fork-pull-request/))

Suppose you have received a pull request in `yourrepo` from `otheruser`.

Add the other user as a remote

```
git remote add otheruser https://github.com/otheruser/yourrepo.git
```

Fetch

```
git fetch otheruser
```

Create a branch from their repo

```
git checkout -b otheruser-master otheruser/master
```

Now make some changes and commit.  Push to their repo

```
git push otheruser HEAD:master
```

Answer (score 7):

Not unless `barryceelen` gives you push access to his fork. You'll have to close his pull request and open a new one from your branch that includes his commits.

Not being able to do what you want to do is annoying. To make better use of GitHub flow, I'd suggest asking forkers to open issues separately from their pull requests that solve them, meaning you can keep the initial conversation flow and have it closed by whatever pull request you decide as the best.

Answer (score 1):

I use the new [`gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli) cli tool.

```sh
gh pr checkout PR_NUMBER
```

Then make your changes and as long as you have access to push to their fork (which from my experience is usually the case if you own the primary repo). With using the `gh` tool, it will basically copy their `branch`'s name so you can do.

```sh
git push git@github.com:other_user/repo branch:branch
```