# How to merge a cloned and edited pull request?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a pull request according to the simple instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419895/5783745), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request/28622034#28622034).

I have edited the cloned PR locally, and now I want to merge it to be the new version of the software. How do I do this?

#### What I've tried so far

I tried the following

```
git add . 
git commit -m "minor edits to pr"
git push
```

and saw

```
fatal: The current branch pullrequest has no upstream branch. 
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use 
git push --set-upstream origin pullrequest
```

So I then ran `git push --set-upstream origin pullrequest`

I now see

[image]

where the PR in the green box is the one i'm trying to edit and merge

Comment: Do you own the pull request highlighted in green? If not, that could explain why you're seeing what you've highlighted in red. Any changes pushed by the owner will be reflected if you choose to merge that pull request. Assuming you're not the owner, you've taken a copy of their branch, made some edits, and thus you must open a new pull request (unless you can push to the remote branch used to open the existing pull request).

Comment: @the pr in green is the one someone else made, and I cloned it, edited it, and I'm trying to merge the edited version. (the green pr appeared after I did the things I mention in the question - I'm not sure what it means)

Comment: @miqh [here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/netstat/pulls)'s the PR if it helps

Comment: Alrighty then. If the pull request was created with ["Allow edits from maintainers" option checked](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) then [this guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) lays it out pretty well. Basically, you need to have pushed your additional commits directly on top of their forked branch for those changes to appear in the opened pull request (green).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, what I did was

- merged the PR as-is, then
- merged the PR I made (containing the edits) immediately afterward

This resulted in 2 pull requests (rather than rolling my edits into the original)

I couldn't work out out how to edit the original PR, although it is possible that as maintainer I did not have permission to do so. (although [even that's unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033729/how-to-tell-if-a-pull-request-has-given-the-maintainer-the-ability-to-edit-the-p))