# How to tell if a pull request has given the maintainer the ability to edit the pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

The initiator of a pull request may [give the maintainer the ability to edit the pull request](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork).

For any given pull request, how can we tell if that ability has been granted? (preferably I would like to know via the browser, but cli is also fine)

#### For clarity

Here's the specifics of the case I'm trying to solve:

- I created a repo with some code
- Someone forked it, made changes, made a PR
- I want to make some adjustments before merging their PR
- As maintainer, I [may or may not have permission to edit the PR before merging](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork)
- How do I find out whether or not I have been granted this permission?

#### UPDATE

I have lodged a ticket with github support and will update the question with anything I find.

As a last resort, I will try to solve by creating dummy github accounts, make two identical PRs to two identical repos (one with edit permissions granted and another without), to see if I can spot the difference). If anyone does this first, please answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Update February 2023)*

This is now displayed on the PR on GitHub:

[image: Maintainers are allowed to edit this pull request]

See blog post: [See when a Pull Request is editable by maintainers](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-02-10-see-when-a-pull-request-is-editable-by-maintainers/)

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE**

As of Feb 2023, please ignore this answer and see [@Jmini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76016312/5783745)'s answer.

**Outdated answer**

From github support:

> Unfortunately there isn't a filter to see which pull requests have allowed edits from maintainers.
>
> Currently, the only way you will know if the pull request author has selected `Allow Edits` from Maintainers is if you try to edit files from the pull request.
>
> For example, if you select a pull request from the fork parent's repository, there will be Files Changed tab. See screenshot below - if you see the Edit file button greyed out, it means the user has not allowed edits from maintainers.

[image]

Comment: whelp, that's better than nothing. Thanks @stevec for chasing down github support on this issue, so that I and other do not have to